# How do i make a very basic useState hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to make a very basic useState hook in React, but cant figure out what im doing wrong.
This is a simple useState that changes the text inside the paragraph to whatever you write in the textfield.

```
export default function Demo() {

const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
const handleValue= () => {
    setValue(value)
}
  
return(

  <>
    <TextField onChange={handleValue} />
    <p>{value}</p>
  </>

 )
}
```

The paragraph doesn't render anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: `value` is the stateful `const`. It starts as `undefined`. `setValue(value)` will only set it to `undefined` again.

Comment: You forgot to give a default value to the `value` state. Try using `React.useState(0)` to set the default value of `value` to be `0`

Comment: You need to set predefine a default value inside `React.useState(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleChange`  function is currently setting the value to itself. You must assign it to the value obtained from the `TextField`.

Here is a working example.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  Fragment
} = React;

function Demo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const handleValue = ({target}) => {
    setValue(target.value);
  }
  
  return <Fragment>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleValue}/>
      <p>{value}</p>
    </Fragment>;
}

const el = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<Demo/>, el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to handle the value coming out of the change handler and use it to update your state

```
export default function Demo() {

const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
const handleValue= (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
}
  
return(

  <>
    <TextField onChange={handleValue} />
    <p>{value}</p>
  </>

 )
}
```

Comment: I worked, but how did the paragraph got the value property to be targeted like this <p value={value} > ?